# 2000s young adult novel about a girl in a medieval-type time, whose uncle wants to use to access another dimension and summon elementals

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

A young adult novel from the 2000s, set in a medieval-type era. The main character is a girl whose parents are killed (I can't remember why) and she is living with her uncle.

She finds out that he wants to use her as she can access some 5th plane or dimension and summon elementals. She has a cat that comes to visit her.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be "[Daughter of Storms](https://www.louisecooper.com/fiction/ya_dos_excerpt.html)" (1996) by Louise Cooper?

The main character is a young girl, she lives with her uncle, her parents are dead, she uses her powers to summon "elementals" from a higher plane, she has cats.

> Innocent of the power she controls, 16-year-old Shar is of great value to others - who lie patiently waiting for such a soul. But as Shar begins to realize her gift, the terror begins and a deadly power is rising. Can Shar summon the elements to become the Dark Caller?

[image: book cover depicting the face of a woman with short, curly red hair; her eyes are closed and some white streaks are circling her head]

Answer (score -1):

*Reserved for the Cat* (*Elemental Masters* #5, 2007) By Mercedes Lackey.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176874.Reserved_for_the_Cat):

> In 1910, in an alternate London, a penniless young dancer is visited by a cat who communicates with her mind to mind. Though she is certain she must be going mad, she is desperate enough to follow the cat's advice and impersonates a famous Russian ballerina. The cat, it turns out, is actually an Elemental Earth Spirit, and leads her to minor stardom.
>
> Meanwhile, the real Russian ballerina has fallen victim to an evil troll who takes over her body and kills her patrons, drinking their life essences in order to strengthen his powers. And soon, the troll focuses his dark attentions on the young dancer...

[image: book cover, mostly red, cat laying on the top of a portrait frame depicting a woman with crossed arms]

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the correct answer?

Comment: Yeah. The time period is all wrong and she doesn't live with her uncle. The only things which match up are elemental magic and the existence of a cat in the book.

Comment: Just to clarify, if you post a wrong answer, but provide the items which do match (and, honestly, the ones that don't), you generally don't get voted down because you made an honest try, and it can help people narrow down the possibilities.